# Remove main product image from gallery (and placeholder)

Tags: error, theme, image, gallery, placeholder

Steps:

1. I have a configurable product with main image for thumbnail and everything else.
2. I create a variation with it's own image.
3. I select hidden in product page in the main product's image.
4. Placerholder is shown.
5. I select a color and now the image is shown.
6. Problem: the gallery shows two items, one being the placeholder.
   [image: problem]
   Why is this the expected behabior? Makes no sense to show the place holder in the gallery.

How can I remove the placeholder an only leave the simple products images?

I have my own custom theme with some very little edits of luma.

Answer (score -1):

you can check below answer may be this answer will help yo to do your task.

[How to Change Product Images with external Image url in all magento 2 frontend and Backend Image display?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309817/how-to-change-product-images-with-external-image-url-in-all-magento-2-frontend-a/309826#309826)

hope this will helpful for you.

Thank you