# Get Sku on list image phtml file

Tags: magento2, product-images, cdn

I am setting up a new site using 2.4.2 and need to use existing product images which are set up on a CDN, in the following formats:
https://website-list.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx.jpg
https://website-thumb.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx.jpg
https://website-zoom.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx.jpg
where xxxxxx is the product sku.

Because of this structure I can't just edit the base media url

I was trying to just hardcode the main url path in and then get the sku, so I need to be able to getSku() on the image phtmls that are part of the category lists etc, as well as standard product view. Currently I'm working on \themefolder\mag-catalog\templates\product\image_with_borders.phtml. Trying something like this:

```
src="https://website-thumb.s3.amazonaws.com/<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSku() ?>.jpg"
```

I can get ProductId but not Sku. It just comes back blank.

I thought if I set Yes on the Attribute page for "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" and "Used in Product Listing" that it would make this Sku attribute available but it makes no difference.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit - I got this to work:

```
$product_id = $block->getProductId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$sku = $product->getSku();
```

Is there any reason not to do it this way?

Comment: Now that I try on the product view page and see how the gallery etc works, and thinking about all the places product images appear, maybe I'd be better off trying to somehow overwrite how the image Urls are created in the whole site? If that's at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

create preference  for **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image** as
**vendor\module\Block\Product\Image.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace vendor\module\Block\Product;

/**
 * Product image block
 *
 * @api
 * @method string getImageUrl()
 * @method string getWidth()
 * @method string getHeight()
 * @method string getLabel()
 * @method float getRatio()
 * @method string getCustomAttributes()
 * @method string getClass()
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Image extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image
{
    /**
     * @deprecated 102.0.5 Property isn't used
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
     */
    protected $imageHelper;

    /**
     * @deprecated 102.0.5 Property isn't used
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @deprecated 102.0.5 Property isn't used
     * @var array
     */
    protected $attributes = [];

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        if (isset($data['template'])) {
            $this->setTemplate($data['template']);
            unset($data['template']);
        }
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductSku($prodid)
{
    return $product->getSku();
}
```

then ur template file

```
 $block->getProductSku($prodid)
```

Comment: Thanks - I just tried that but it's giving me an error. Should i be able to just put that straight into the phtml file? I'm getting:ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file in /home/website/public_html/app/design/frontend/website/luma_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml:20

Comment: In the meantime I got code to work - have edited the question  - any reason not to use that version?

Comment: i have updated my ans

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise there wer 2 answers here. I have already created a module following the instructions on this SE - magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309817/… - which is working for some lists and the main product item page, but not the minicart, checkout or Recently Viewed widget (this is because it's using js I think, different type of page). I will have a look at your solution and see does it work any better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call objectmanager.

You should extend the Block class in order to receive the productrepository on it's constructor and get the sku that way :)

Here is how to do it. On you di.xml (**etc/di.xml**) place the following code

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image"          type="vendor\module\Preferences\Product\Image"/>
```

Now under **vendor\module\Preferences\Product** let's create the file **Image.php** and place the following code in it

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Preferences\Product;


class Image extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    
    protected $imageHelper;
    protected $product;
    protected $attributes = [];
    protected $_productloader;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory      $productloader
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,      
        array $data = []
    ) {
    
        $this->_productloader = $productloader;
        if (isset($data['template'])) {
            $this->setTemplate($data['template']);
            unset($data['template']);
        }
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    public function getProductSku($productId)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($productId)->getSku();
    }
}
?>
```

After this compile your code and just use `<?= $block->getProductSku($your_product_id); ?>` where you need inside your template. Let me know if it worked for you and/or you need any further assistance

Comment: Thank you, I am only seeing this now. I have already created a module following the instructions on this SE - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309817/how-to-change-product-images-with-external-image-url-in-all-magento-2-frontend-a - which is working for some lists and the main product item page, but not the minicart, checkout or Recently Viewed widget (this is because it's using js I think, different type of page). I will have a look at your solution and see does it work any better, thanks!