# Magento 2.4.6 show external images on listing, checkout, customer account pages

Tags: magento2.4

I want to show external images for products on all the pages.
I have managed to show external image on PDP with below plugin.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery">
    <plugin name="add_images_to_gallery" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery"
            sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

For other pages I have tried below plugin, but not sure how to set external image here. Can anyone please suggest any solution for this.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder">
    <plugin name="product_object_to_image_data" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder"
            sortOrder="10"/>
</type>


class ImageBuilder
{
    public function aroundCreate(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product = null,
        string $imageId = null,
        array $attributes = null
    ) {
        return $proceed($product, $imageId, $attributes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/309826/36384