# Change Order Summary Image

Tags: magento2, checkout-summary

I've been working on a module to change Magento Thumbnails in the Cart, Minicart and Checkout Order Summary.
The only place I cannot get this to work is the Checkout Order Summary. There is a real lack of documentation on how to modify the image thumbnails there.

So far, I have:

```
<?php

namespace Configurable\Products\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\ImageProvider;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem;

class afterGetImages
{
  protected $itemFactory;
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
  ) {
    $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
 }
public function afterGetImages(ImageProvider $subject, array $result): array
 {

 
    foreach ($result as $itemId => $value) {
      /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item **/
      $item = $this->itemFactory->create()->load($itemId);
        if ($item) {
          $productid = $item->getProduct();
        }

    }
 }
}
```

But this returns:

```
Return value must be of type array, none returned on line 31
```

It does not seem to be fetching the data correctly.

Secondly, I can find no information of what argument to modify to change the Order Summary Checkout Image.
Looking at magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart/ImageProvider.php, it includes:

```
$imageData = [
    'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
    'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
    'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
    'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
];
return $imageData;
```

But including this logic in my function:

```
$imageData = [
            'src' => "Image Url",
        ];
        return $imageData;
```

Does not change the image.
I've spend many days on this but I keep hitting a brick wall.
What needs to be changed here to modify the Checkout Order Summary Thumbnails?
I found [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309817/how-to-change-product-images-with-external-image-url-in-all-magento-2-frontend-a) but it didn't seem to change Order Summary Thumbnails for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Trying also, 
$item->setImageUrl("https://static.integromat.com/img/packages/magento_256.png");
But no luck with that.

Comment: I believe this is correct: 
$result = $item['product_image']['src'] = "https://static.integromat.com/img/packages/magento_256.png"
But it gives error Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element